# Align the child views in center of the ViewPager android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, center

I need to set the child view as center of the ViewPager and also I would like to show some part of the next and previous views to the current view sides(like current screen below 1). But currently the current view is starting at left side of the ViewPager(like expected screen below 2). How can I achieve that?

Here is my code..

**MyViewPagerAdapter**

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private int mPageCount;
    public MyViewPagerAdapter(Activity activity,int pageCount) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mPageCount = pageCount;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mPageCount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return (view ==(View)obj);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container,final int position) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.item_view, null);

        viewGroup.setBackgroundColor(randomColor());

        TextView textView = (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText("Page: "+(position+1));
        Button button = (Button) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Hey, Its clicked!!! at page "+(position+1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        container.addView(viewGroup);
        return viewGroup;
    }

    Random rnd = new Random();
    private int randomColor(){
        return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        //must be overridden else throws exception as not overridden.
        Log.d("Tag", collection.getChildCount()+"");
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return 0.8f;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private int ID = 100; 

    private final int count = 8;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        linearLayout  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.indicator_layout);
        generateIndicators(count);


        MyViewPagerAdapter adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(this, count);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            int oldPosition = 0;
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                //this changes the old position's view state image
                ((TextView)linearLayout.getChildAt(oldPosition)).setText("");
                oldPosition = position;


                //this changes the current position's view state image
                ((TextView)linearLayout.getChildAt(position)).setText((position+1)+"");

            }
            //this method will be called repeatedly upto another item comes as front one(active one)
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {


            }
            //this will be called as per scroll state
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {


            }
        });

        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

    }

    private void generateIndicators(int count) {
        /// Converts 14 dip into its equivalent px
        int padd = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 3, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setId(ID+i);
            final int currentItem = i;
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_cell);
            textView.setPadding(padd,padd,padd,padd);
            /// Converts 14 dip into its equivalent px
            int size = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            textView.setTextSize(size);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            /// Converts 14 dip into its equivalent px
            int px = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(px, px);
            linearLayout.addView(textView,params);
        }

        ((TextView)linearLayout.getChildAt(0)).setText("1");

    }





}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/viewPager"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/indicator_layout"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="19dp" >
   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**item_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="click me" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Current screen**
[image: Current screen]

**expected screen**
[image: expected screen]

Comment: I have done this now by customizing the ViewPager.

Comment: Have you got it done? I'm facing the same question @noundla

Comment: yes. Give me your mail id , i can send it to u.

Comment: thanks so much. my address: wangbourne@gmail.com

Comment: I send you mail. check it and let me know.

Comment: Was you able to achieve the expected screen? @noundla

Comment: yes. I can give you. Can you tell me how to post huge lines of code to avail for all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I have added my solution for this question in GitHub. I have done some pretty tricks to get the workaround solution. You can get the project from the below link(Actually I have planned to create a blog with the explanation , but I dint have that much time to do).

Here is the [link](https://github.com/noundla/Sunny_Projects/tree/master/CenterLockViewPager)(https://github.com/noundla/Sunny_Projects/tree/master/CenterLockViewPager)

You have to copy the files from `com.noundla.centerviewpagersample.comps` package to your project. And you can see the usage of that Viewpager in `MainActivity` class.

Please let me know if anyone has problems with this.

Answer (score 12):

For one app I implemented similar the following way, with standard `ViewPager`:

- Make pages full-screen with the actual content in an inner layout. For example, make the full-screen layout a `RelativeLayout` with transparent background and the actual content another `RelativeLayout` centered in the parent. If I remember right, the reason for this was that with just the inner layout as a page, the `ViewPager` would not have taken all the screen width on some devices such as Galaxy Nexus.
- Use `ViewPager.setPageMargin()` to set up a negative page margin i.e. how much of the next/previous page you want to show. Make sure it only overlaps the transparent region of the parent full-screen layout.
- Call `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit()` to adjust the off-screen page count to at least `2` from the default `1` to ensure smooth paging by really creating the pages off-screen. Otherwise you will see next/previous pages being drawn while already partially showing on screen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think this can give result as I am expected, because those views should not come beside if we give the margin. However, I did it by customizing the scrollToItem() method in ViewPager class. I supposed to post my ViewPager class but, It has more characters so, I am unable to post the answer here. I would like to close this question.

Comment: This is how I did it but using FrameLayouts. This idea was to give up using the getPageWidth() (leave it to 1.0f) and use the negative margin to bring in the the adjacent pages. 

In my page layout, I used a root FrameLayout (params don't matter much because they'll be set by the ViewPager) and a child FrameLayout with fixed width were I put all the page's content. Then in my activity I would calculate the negative margin as the following:

margin = viewpager.getWidth() - pageWidth;
viewpager.setPageMargin(-margin);

where pageWidth is the fixed width of the child FrameLayout I specified above

Comment: yup! this did it

Answer (score 10):

For anyone upset that the OP didn't update his question with the solution here is a link that explains, with minimal effort, how to pull this off in XML: http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/14/android-tip-viewpager-with-protruding-children/

Basically when you declare your viewpager in XML, give it the same left and right padding and set android:clipToPadding="false".  (The clipToPadding is missing in his xml sample and necessary to achieve this effect)

Answer (score 2):

I found solution in this [post](http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/android-viewpager-cards-1), below the code i used:

```
// Offset between sibling pages in dp
int pageOffset = 20;

// Visible part of sibling pages at the edges in dp
int sidePageVisibleWidth = 10;

// Horizontal padding will be
int horPadding = pageOffset + sidePageVisibleWidth;

// Apply parameters
viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
viewPager.setPageMargin(UIUtil.dpToPx(pageOffset, getContext()));
viewPager.setPadding(UIUtil.dpToPx(horPadding, getContext()), 0, UIUtil.dpToPx(horPadding, getContext()), 0);
```

dpToPx code:

```
 public static int dpToPx(int dp, Context context) {
        float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return Math.round((float) dp * density);
    }
```

This is all you need

Answer (score 1):

You can use padding for viewPager and set **clipToPadding** false

**Java**

```
viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
viewPager.setPadding(50, 0, 50, 0);
```

**Kotlin**

```
 viewPager.clipToPadding = false
 viewPager.setPadding(50, 0, 50, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to **center current page** in view pager with **different page widths**, so solution with paddings was not suitable. Also user scrolling was disabled (it was tab bar view pager, scrolled by another view pager). Here is a very simple solution to do that - just override ViewPager.ScrollTo method just like this (C# code, Xamarin):

```
public override void ScrollTo(int x, int y)
{
    x -= (int) (MeasuredWidth * (1 - Adapter.GetPageWidth(CurrentItem)) / 2);

    base.ScrollTo(x, y);
}
```

And if you calculate page width for each fragment don't forget to cache them in array.

Answer (score -2):

Extend **HorizontalScrollView** class as the parent for the scrolling view. In the **onMeasure()** method you can specify the width and height of each child. Little cumbersome way but the effect will be good and you can have a good hold on your child view.