# Partially show the next and the previous item when using JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am using JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator and i am trying to get an effect were the current item is fully visible while the next and the previous items are just partially visible. Any ideas of how i go about achieving this.

Comment: and by "current item" you mean current *page*, not current page *title*?

Comment: i mean current page. I dont want to have titles

Answer (score 1):

1. [`ViewPagerIndicator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) has nothing to do with this. It just provides with some sort of titles of pages (not necessarily text-based). To make it work you will need to work with the [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) itself and its [`PagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html).
2. You need to override [`getPageWidth`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getPageWidth(int)) method of your `PagerAdapter` and make it return a float value `<1.0f` for pages (positions) that you don't want to fit the whole width of the screen. If you want the same behaviour for all pages of your `ViewPager`, just make `getPageWidth` return a fixed value `<1.0f`. So for example it could've looked like that:

   ```
   @Override
   public float getPageWidth(int position) {
       return 0.75f;
   }
   ```
3. The previous step will result in something like this:

[image: unaligned]

And I assume your goal looks more like this:

[image: aligned]

And it's not really that easy to transition between those two ways of displaying pages by a `ViewPager` (it does not provide with any default way to change gravity of pages or something). And to make your `ViewPager` display those pages in the center of the `View` you will need to struggle a bit. There are few threads on SO about that. Ones that I think might help you are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212591/align-the-child-views-in-center-of-the-viewpager-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12286698/1993204). Apart from that you can use [this](https://jjyap.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/android-mutiple-view-viewpager-with-centering/) approach.